# values of elements don't change

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have the following Code:

asp.net-Code

```
..
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="some text" aria-label="note" id="note" aria-describedby="basic-addon3" runat="server">
..
```

c#-Code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    note.Value = "some other text";
}

private void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveValue(note.Value);
}
```

If I hit the Button that calls the SaveValue-Function it always saves the value that I've set before on Page_Load, and not the Value I've entered on the Page itself.

What Do I have to do, to get the actual Value that is set in the input-field?

Comment: Can I ask why you're using Web Forms? Is that by choice? Or was that decision forced on you by your school or company?

Comment: One thing comes to the other. I've searched for one language that supports as many features as possible for my interests (classic programming, web, IoT). So I come to C# and Web Forms. At this moment it was the easiest part for to learn Web Forms because it's very near to the classic WinForms. I also don't know at this moment that there're other "better" ways to Create Web Pages with C# ;-)

Comment: Sure, C# is great. Web Forms is not. Web Forms is dying or dead. It's not receiving any updates, it's not being ported to ASP.NET Core. It completely ignores fundamental web concepts in favor of some poor emulation of Win Forms, despite the fact that running on the web is nothing like a desktop app. Postbacks, ViewState, UpdatePanel, ASMX, SqlDataSource, all these terrible things to build your app on. Instead, you should embrace ASP.NET MVC (preferably Core, but even non-Core you'll learn the right concepts) or learn a JavaScript framework backed by ASP.NET Web API.

Comment: I just hate to see someone new to web development waste their time on a framework that's going to encourage a lot of bad designs and cause a lot of frustration, and not have the knowledge really translate to what the rest of the web development community is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change your code little bit

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        note.Value = "some other text";
    }
}
```

In ASP.NET, there is something called the page life cycle. When you do something on the page to cause a postback (such as clicking a Button control) the page will send an HTTP POST request to the same URL. When this happens, the IsPostBack property of the page will be set to true. Any time the page is loaded, whether via the first request or a subsequent postback, the Page_Load event will fire, before any button click event handlers are called.

This means that you were resetting the value of `note`  before your button click handler was reached. To prevent this, your Page_Load event should check the IsPostBack property to make sure it's not overwriting the value coming from the user.

For more detail see this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_life_cycle.htm).

Comment: yeah I have updated the answer with some details to help :)

Comment: That was better, though I updated the wording on it because it was very difficult to understand.

Comment: Great! Many thanks to you! Now I not only know how to fix it, I also understand why this happens.